# Коннект Python к SAP R/3

Tags: python, sap

Нужно подключиться из python 3.8 к SAP R3.
Поиск по гуглу привел к 2 методам 
через Dispatch("SAP.Functions") 
и через pyrfc. 
так как для pyrfc нужно устанавливать доп пакеты. Хотелось бы подключиться через Dispatch("SAP.Functions") 
Дабы все работало от базового клиента
Пишем код

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import inspect

f = Dispatch("SAP.Functions") 
f.Connection.User = 'aa'
f.Connection.LogOn(0,False)

на строчке f.Connection.username = 'aa' получаем 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python\SAP\saptest1.py", line 5, in <module>
    f.Connection.User = 'aa'
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 559, in __setattr__
    self._oleobj_.Invoke(entry.dispid, 0, invoke_type, 0, value)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352562, 'Недопустимое число параметров.', None, None)


Добавление любых строк к F приводит к этой ошибке
```

Поиск по инету приводит к такому коду где утверждается что все работает 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52153056/set-query-parameters-of-rfc-read-table-using-win32com-module

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
Functions = Dispatch("SAP.Functions")

Functions.Connection.Client = "400"
Functions.Connection.ApplicationServer = "myserver"
Functions.Connection.Language = "EN"
Functions.Connection.User = "myuser"
Functions.Connection.Password = "mypwd"
Functions.Connection.SystemNumber = "00"
Functions.Connection.UseSAPLogonIni = False
if (Functions.Connection.Logon (0,True) == True):
    print("Logon OK")
```

Причем у меня есть код на MSSQL сервере где установлен стандартный клиент сапа и MSSQL сервер из stored procedure коннектится нормально к сапу. Через SAP.Functions и параметры передаются

То что оле объект рабочий и он есть это подтверждается запуском такого кода

```
f = Dispatch("SAP.Functions") 
f.Connection.LogOn(0,False)
```

Вызывается стандартный логин сапа и просит ввести данные. 
Мне нужно избежать диалогового окна  и подключиться автоматически.

Что не так делаю?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

В общем пару дней  долбился.. Вот решение

```py
from win32com.client.dynamic import Dispatch

LogonControl = Dispatch("SAP.LogonControl.1")
objConnection = LogonControl.NewConnection
objConnection.user = 'user'
objConnection.password = 'password'
objConnection.client = '013'
objConnection.applicationserver = 'ipaddres'
objConnection.systemnumber = '03'
objConnection.usesaplogonini = False

if not objConnection.Logon(0, True):
    print('LogonError....')
else:
     print('LogonOK....')

f = Dispatch("SAP.Functions")
f.Connection = objConnection
RFC = f.Add("RFC_READ_TABLE")
RFC.Exports("QUERY_TABLE").Value = "ZPGAUTOADDMAT"
RFC.Exports("ROWCOUNT").Value = "100"
RFC.Exports("DELIMITER").Value = ";"
if RFC.Call == False:
    print('Error call function')
else:
    tblOptions = RFC.Tables("OPTIONS")
    tblData = RFC.Tables("DATA")
    tblFields = RFC.Tables("FIELDS")
    print(tblFields.RowCount)
    print(tblFields(1,"FIELDNAME"))
    row = 1
    while row <= tblData.RowCount:
        print(tblData(row,(1)))
        row = row + 1
```

**Обязательно атрибуты objConnection  маленькими буквами !!!**

```py
objConnection.user = 'USERNAME'
objConnection.password = 'password'
objConnection.client = '013'
objConnection.applicationserver = 'ipaddres'
objConnection.systemnumber = '03'
objConnection.usesaplogonini = False
```

В этом был вся трудность. Я взял чужой код, где написано все работает. 
Но пока случайно не сделал маленькими буквами, 
ничего не работало.
Хотя у меня в MSSQL через stored procedure, написаны с большой буквы все атрибуты и там работает.